scraping json with scrapy item loaders
Updated after heads up from @wRAR
I am following this example for scraping a news website. When I check the type returned in his case, the type is a scrapy.selector.unified.SelectorList.
In my case, since the data of interest is enclosed in <script> tags I managed to extract and parse it in the form of a List via the below python code.
fetch('https://newswebsite.com/news/national')

data = re.findall("<script type=.application.ld.json. id=.listing-ld.>{.@graph.:(.+?),.@context.:.http:..schema.org..<.script>", response.body.decode("utf-8"), re.S)

#convert list to string before converting to json
jsonData = json.loads(''.join(data))


Having return a List I cannot keep following the example to implement item loaders
Could you guide me on what python concepts are in use in the below code so I can familiarize myself and be able to adapt it to my use case?
Trying to understand what is the for loop doing..
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class ChocolateProductLoader(ItemLoader):

    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    price_in = MapCompose(lambda x: x.split("£")[-1])
    url_in = MapCompose(lambda x: 'https://www.chocolate.co.uk' + x )

import scrapy
from chocolatescraper.itemloaders import ChocolateProductLoader
from chocolatescraper.items import ChocolateProduct  

 
class ChocolateSpider(scrapy.Spider):

   # The name of the spider
   name = 'chocolatespider'

   # These are the urls that we will start scraping
   start_urls = ['https://www.chocolate.co.uk/collections/all']

   def parse(self, response):
       products = response.css('product-item')

       for product in products:
            chocolate = ChocolateProductLoader(item=ChocolateProduct(), selector=product)
            chocolate.add_css('name', "a.product-item-meta__title::text")
            chocolate.add_css('price', 'span.price', re='<span class="price">\n              <span class="visually-hidden">Sale price</span>(.*)</span>')
            chocolate.add_css('url', 'div.product-item-meta a::attr(href)')
            yield chocolate.load_item()

       next_page = response.css('[rel="next"] ::attr(href)').get()

       if next_page is not None:
           next_page_url = 'https://www.chocolate.co.uk' + next_page
           yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)


"the item being loaded in the item loader before being parsed" is not something that happens in this code. As for explaining some external code, I'm not sure this is ontopic for SO. You should ask specific questions about your code.

Hi!
As a solution, I would recommend to use the ItemLoader in a separate function. The problem is that you are trying to use a generative expression with the ItemLoader, but the Item loader only works with return.
There are two options here:
Generate an instance of the class immediately through yield.
for product in products:
    yield ChocolateProductItem(
        name=response.css('a.product-item-meta__title::text').get(),
        ...
    )

Or, what I think is the best solution, define a separate function to create an entry about a new item and use ItemLoader + return in it.
...
    for product in products:
        # here you should get url from product and pass it in url variable below
        # ? may be like that - it depends on the contents of the porduct
        # url = product.css(':attr(href)').get()
        yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                callback=self.parse_item,
            )

def parse_item(self, response):
    """
    Scrape a product page.
    """
    loader = ItemLoader(item=ChocolateProductItem(), response=response)
    loader.add_css('name', 'a.product-item-meta__title')
    # And here, please note, I don't get ::text right away, there is a beautiful way to use the input and output processors in the ItemLoader to get the necessary data from the string. I`ll write about it bellow.
    ...
    return loader.load_item()

# items.py
# you can, of course, leave it as it was with you. and it's so good, I'm just sharing my vision

class ChocolateProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, clean_data),
        output_processor=TakeFirst(),
    )
    ...

I hope I helped!
Good luck!
